# Swift 4 backwards compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have the following code in my project in Xcode 8.3.3 (Swift 3.1):

```
let font = CGFont(provider!)
CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)
```

But in Xcode 9 Beta (Swift 4), I get the following error:

> Value of optional type 'CGFont?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use
>   '!' or '?'?

The error is because the [initializer for CGFont](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfont/1396367-init?changes=latest_minor) that takes a `CGDataProvider` now returns an optional.

But when I apply the fix of:

```
let font = CGFont(provider)
CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font!, &error)
```

The code no longer compiles in Xcode 8.3.3 with Swift 3.1 since font is not an optional and thus doesn't play nicely with the `!`.

**Is there a way to make this work in both versions of Xcode? Is Swift 4 supposed to be backwards compatible (compile with Swift 3 compiler)?**

Comment: I'd say this is a breaking change in Core Graphics (initializer has become failable), so it has nothing to do with Swift 4. But I think you could use conditional compilation to work around this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using the following method which allowed for backwards compatibility without conditional compilation (idea taken from [this blog post](http://radex.io/xcode7-xcode8/)):

```
func optionalize<T>(_ x: T?) -> T? {
    return x
}
```

This way in both Xcode 8 and Xcode 9 I could use:

```
guard let font = optionalize(CGFont(provider)) else {
    return
}
CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a breaking change in Core Graphics not in Swift itself. API has changed, the initializer is now failable.

Use [conditional compilation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH33-ID538) to make your code compile with both 3.1 and 4.0 compiler:

```
#if swift(>=4.0)
let font = CGFont(provider!)
#else
let font = CGFont(provider)!
#endif

CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error)
```

Comment: If I use this then I noticed even in Xcode 9 I was hitting the 'else' case. So I went to my project settings and changed `Swift Language Version` to Swift 4.0. But now again if I open in Xcode 8 then it complains about an unsupported swift version...

Comment: @AdamJohns Perhaps the problem is that the new compiler is still in beta, so it might have a version like 4.0.beta... Try changing the version in the conditional compilation statement to 3.3 (or other nonexistent 3.x version).
Or, to avoid guessing, run `swiftc --version` as one of the build phase scripts to see the exact version of Swift compiler in Xcode 9 and 8.3.
Maybe Xcode 9 uses the older version of command line tools (check Locations tab in Xcode settings).